# Big Renaming Project

Tags: html

I'm about to start a renaming project on a major data driven website USING VISUAL STUDIO and WINDOWS XP.  I've got a script to change the company name in the data/tempates thousands of times.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can verify that all of the names have been changed?  Is there a way to pull the generated files down to my disk so I can grep it out?

Comment: language? platform? IDE?

Comment: I guess more info on the platform/technologies you are using are needed...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I added development env and OS.  This is my first post here and I guess my mind was windows-centric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use any specific web server or publishing system? But perhaps one huge, recursive **wget** is enough?

Comment: Would probably also be very helpful to OP if you posted instructions; recursive WGET isn't exactly easy.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a website crawler that can save retrieved pages to disk. There are many programs of this kind available on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio offers a Find In File (ctrl+shift+f). Search for what you need and it will list all the location of what it was able to find.

Review and replace.

Comment: Good idea but the site is data driven from several sources.  I'm worried about missing one or more.

Comment: Though that your solution was in Visual Studio, but turns out that its more than one solution. Good luck :D